# perl load json from file and loop

Tags: json, perl

I've got a file like this:

```
{
    "dev":
    {
        "data": "1"
    },
    "stg":
    {
        "data": "1"
    },
    "pre":
    {
        "data": "1"
    },
    "prod":
    {
        "data": "1"
    },
}
```

I load the json like this:

```
open(FH,"<",$file) or die "environments.json file doesn't exists!\n";
my $data = <FH>;

my $ret = JSON::decode_json( $data );
```

It loads properly, I can do:

```
print "Dumper: " .  Dumper($ret) . "\n";
```

But when I try to loop through it with:

```
foreach my $env( @$ret )
{
    print "Environment: " . $env->{"data"} . "\n";
}
```

I get:

```
Not an ARRAY reference at ./launcher.pl line 20, <FH> line 1.
```

On the `foreach my $env( @$ret )` line
Help is appreciated!

Thanks!

David

Comment: Re "*It loads properly*", I doubt that. That's not valid JSON. (trailing comma).

Answer (score 2):

There's no array in that JSON.

```
for my $env_name (keys(%$ret)) {
   my $env = $ret->{$env_name};

   ... $env->{data} ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had already figured it out, but didn't report it. Usign "foreach my $env( keys %{$ret} )"